# How to use tags from yaml file - terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, yaml, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to extract certain tags from a YAML file with Terraform, but i just don't know how.
Yaml file looks like this:

```
--- 
name: subscriptionName 
emailContact: someemail@domain.com 
tags:
  - key: "tagKey1"
    value: "tagValue1"
  - key: "tagKey2"
    value: "tagValue2"
  - key: "tagKey3"
    value: "tagValue3"
  - key: "tagKey4"
    value: "tagValue4"
```

What i am interested in is getting 2 (let's say key1 and key3) key-value pairs as tags and tag resouces. I know that 'locals' plays a role here, but i am kinda new to terraform and cannot get any resource tagged.
The resources are Azure (if it matters).

The resource i am trying to tag is:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
name                = "randomname"
location = "westeurope"
resource_group_name = "random_rg"
tags { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want **two random tags**, you can use [random_shuffle](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/shuffle):

```
locals {
    loaded_yaml = yamldecode(file("./your_file.yaml"))
}

resource "random_shuffle" "indices" {
  input        = range(0, length(local.loaded_yaml.tags))
  result_count = 2
  seed = timestamp()
}

output "random_tags" {
    value = [for idx in random_shuffle.indices.result: 
             local.loaded_yaml.tags[idx]]
}
```

**update**
For example:

```
    tags = {
            (local.loaded_yaml.tags[0].key) = local.loaded_yaml.tags[0].value
            (local.loaded_yaml.tags[3].key) = local.loaded_yaml.tags[3].value
        }
```

Comment: I need two specific tags from that. WHen i said Key1 and 3 i meant i need two tags from there that i can choose, Either 1 and 4 or 2 and 3 and so on. It cannot be random.

Comment: @Alex Then you just access them directly, `local.loaded_yaml.tags[2]` and `local.loaded_yaml.tags[3]`.

Comment: @Alex If you don't want random, why did you write `random` in question?

Comment: I have removed 'random' word. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How would those two values would look like into the `resource {}` section?
This doesn't work:
`tags = {
    local.tags_list[0]
    local.tags_list[8] }`

Comment: @Alex I don't know which `resource {} section`. You haven't provided any code for that. Please make new question for this specific issue.

Comment: added resource in question

Comment: @Alex Your new code is not even a valid TF code.

Comment: Coming here was a long shot, i thought, getting a simple answer, but i guess i'm asking too much. Sorry for any time spent on this.
All i want is to extract two tags from an yaml file.  Even added a resource code for network security group in Azure Portal just to show where i need the tags to go into.
What else is missing?

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Also i appreciate the patience!

Comment: @Alex No problem. Glad it worked out:-)